# How to solve the “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null”

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

I have ‘n’ number of check box. 
The check box displays:

```
<?php 
$result=mysql_query("select * from tablename where status='approved'");
$result1=$count=mysql_result(mysql_query("select max(id) from tablename  where status='approved'"),0);
$limit=mysql_num_rows($result);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){?> 

<input type="checkbox" name="chekgrp[]" id="cheks_<?php echo $row['id'];?>"  onclick="Checkchk()" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"  />
<?php }
?>
```

The value n is set in a hidden field

```
<input type ="hidden" value="<?php echo $limit; ?>" id="hiddenval" name=" hiddenval">
```

The javascript validation is:

```
var limits=parseInt(document.form.hiddenval.value);
var countelm=0;
for(i=1;i<= limits;i++){
    if (("cheks_"+i).length>0){
    if(document.getElementById("cheks_"+i).checked)
        {
            countelm = countelm +1;
        }
    }
}
```

It shows the above error if change the status to unapproved an element from table. I know it’s because I have changed the status of  certain element. Is there any other way to check if element exists (checking length doesn't help) ? How to solve this error? Please help me.

Comment: What is `("cheks_"+i).length` referring to?

Comment: What's the point of `if (("cheks_"+i).length>0)`? It's always going to be `true`

Comment: @Phil, 3 seconds :)))

Comment: Just check if the DOM node exists before checking for it's `checked` property, using `document.getElementById("cheks_"+i) && document.getElementById("cheks_"+i).checked`

Comment: I'd say the problem here is that nothing in this guarantees the resultset `id` columns to be contiguous (eg, 1, 2, 3, 4...). Using a `for` loop makes an assumption that the checkboxes have contiguous suffixes. You'll probably have better luck using `document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="cheks_"]')`

Comment: It shows the error because certain element doesn't exits. How to check if element exits or not?

Comment: @ Phil Yes I understand . But I really need to take the count in javascript. Is there any other way to solve this error?

Comment: Sorry for the typos

Comment: Is `$limit` the maximum number (count) of checkboxes to check or the maximum `id` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

1. Use `document.querySelectorAll` to find all your checkboxes
2. `Array.prototype.slice` to truncate the list to `$limit` items
3. `Array.prototype.filter` to limit the list to the `checked` ones, and
4. `Array.prototype.length` to get the count

HTML / PHP

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chekgrp[]" id="cheks_<?= $row['id'] ?>" onclick="Checkchk()" value="<?= $row['id'] ?>" />
```

JS

```
var limits = parseInt(document.getElementById('hiddenval').value, 10)
var selector = 'input[type="checkbox"][name="chekgrp[]"]'
var countelm = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), 0, limits)
    .filter(function(checkbox) { return checkbox.checked })
    .length
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked) this shows some error.

Comment: @Adrian what browser are you using? Must be pretty old. I've updated my answer with a more *compatible* version

Comment: Thank you so much Phil. You really made my day.